# Responsive Design Disfunctional in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, responsive-design, media-queries

So, I've been building sites for a good while, mainly utilizing Zurb Foundations for layout and responsive features. Recently, for the first time, I decided to hack it out from the ground up using media queries. My CSS is a little wonky (I, for some reason, had to push my second section down by 260px to avoid overlapping the first) but does the job just fine in Chrome. In Firefox and Safari however the two sections remain atop one another. Can anyone recommend a CSSolution for my issue?

Thanks,
John

```css
/*home.css*/
p {
 font-family: 'Droid Sans';
 font-size: .8em;
}
h1, h2, h1 > a {
 font-size: 1.2em; 
 font-weight: normal;
}
.landscape {
  background-image: url("../img/landscape1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 327px;
  margin: 0 auto; 
}
/*Styling for the Request A Quote form*/
.quote {
 background-color: green;
 font-size: .7em;
 color: white;
 z-index: -1;
}
.quote > h2 {
  color: #fff; 
  font-size: 1.2me
  
}
input {
  display: block;
  width:180px;
  color:black;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 7px; 
}
#submit {
  width: 80px; 
}
/*Landscape image settings for large screens*/
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
 .landscape {
  width: 890px;
  height: 327px;
  max-width: 1000px; 
 }
 .your-yard-left {
  border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px;
  width: 70%;
 }
 
}
/*Form styles for large screen*/
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
 .quote {
  float: right;
   width: 220px; 
   height: 327px;
   border-radius: 0 25px 25px 0;
   padding: 0 15px;
  }
  .offer {
   display: none;
  }
  .your-yard-left {
  border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px;
  width: 70%;
 }
 
}
/*Landscape styles for 700 > 900px screens*/
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
 .landscape {
  height: 327px;
 }
 .your-yard-left {
  border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px;
  width: 70%;
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
 .landscape {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
 }
 .quote {
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
  border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  height: 240px;
  float: none;
  width: 60%;
 }
 form, .quote > h2 {
  padding: 0 10px;
 }
 input {
  width: 250px;
 }
 .offer {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  background-color: #A8CD1B;
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 40%;
  min-width: 120px;
  height: 240px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 0 0 25px 0;

 }
 .offer > p { 
  color: black;
  font-size: .8em;
 }

 .your-yard-left {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
  border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px;
  width: 70%;
 }
 .your-yard-right {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -50px; 
  height: 260px;
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
 .offer {
  width: 30%;
 }
 .quote {
  width: 70%;
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
 .offer {
  display: none;
 }
 .quote {
  width: 100%;
 }
 .your-yard-left {
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
  top: 260px;
  overflow: none;
  width: 100%;
 }
 .your-yard-right {
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 260px;
  display: none;
 }
}

.your-yard-left {
 background-color: #A8CD1B;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 10px; 
 padding-right: 2%;
}
.your-yard-left > h2, .your-yard-left > p  {
 margin-left: 10px;
}
.your-yard-right {
 background-color: green;
 border-radius: 0 25px 25px 0;
 margin-top: 10px;
 width: 30%;
 float: right;
 z-index: 1;
 overflow: hidden;

}
.your-yard-right img {
 max-height: 150px;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 10px auto;

}
.center {
 clear: both;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1010px) {
 .your-yard {
  max-width: 1000px;
 }
 .wrap {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
 }
}

.wrap {
 display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Helping Hand Lawn Care</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">

</head>
<body>
  <!--#include virtual="includes/nav.inc"-->
  <div class="landscape">
    <div class="quote">
      <h2>Request A Quote!</h2>
      <form>
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name"><br/>
        <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email"><br/>
        <input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="Phone"><br/>
        <input type="text" id="address" placeholder="Address"><br/>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="offer">
      <h2>We'll Be In Touch</h2>
      <p>Drop us a message and we'll have one of our certified landscape technicians come by, inspect your property and give you a quote. Our prices are always fair and our service always top notch. See what </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="your-yard-left">
       <h2 class="center ">Your Yard, Your Pride, Your Way</h2>
       <p>Since 2003, Helping Hand Lawn Care has serviced homes, businesses and governmental facilities throughout the Central Florida area in full-service landscape maintenance, installation, irrigation and pest control company. Our team has the experience, knowledge and dedication it takes to invision and execute the projects it takes to get your lawn looking great.<p>
      <p>Contact us today to have a landscape professional offer a quote! We offer seasonal and annual packages for all size properties.
    </div>
    <div class="your-yard-right">
      <img src="img/landscape2.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>

    <!--
    <div class="center">
      <h2>Why Helping Hand?</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Quality work</li>
        <li>Consistent arrivals</li>
        <li>Outstanding customer service</li>
        <li>Over 15+ years industry experience</li>
    </div>
    -->



  <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/menu.js"></script>
  <!-- Other JS plugins can be included here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have add one property this media query

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
.wrap {
display: inherit !important;
}
}
```

```css
/*home.css*/
p {
 font-family: 'Droid Sans';
 font-size: .8em;
}
h1, h2, h1 > a {
 font-size: 1.2em; 
 font-weight: normal;
}
.landscape {
  background-image: url("../img/landscape1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 327px;
  margin: 0 auto; 
}
/*Styling for the Request A Quote form*/
.quote {
 background-color: green;
 font-size: .7em;
 color: white;
 z-index: -1;
}
.quote > h2 {
  color: #fff; 
  font-size: 1.2me
  
}
input {
  display: block;
  width:180px;
  color:black;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 7px; 
}
#submit {
  width: 80px; 
}
/*Landscape image settings for large screens*/
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
 .landscape {
  width: 890px;
  height: 327px;
  max-width: 1000px; 
 }
 .your-yard-left {
  border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px;
  width: 70%;
 }
 
}
/*Form styles for large screen*/
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
 .quote {
  float: right;
   width: 220px; 
   height: 327px;
   border-radius: 0 25px 25px 0;
   padding: 0 15px;
  }
  .offer {
   display: none;
  }
  .your-yard-left {
  border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px;
  width: 70%;
 }
 
}
/*Landscape styles for 700 > 900px screens*/
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
 .landscape {
  height: 327px;
 }
 .your-yard-left {
  border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px;
  width: 70%;
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
 .landscape {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
 }
 .quote {
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
  border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  height: 240px;
  float: none;
  width: 60%;
 }
 form, .quote > h2 {
  padding: 0 10px;
 }
 input {
  width: 250px;
 }
 .offer {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  background-color: #A8CD1B;
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 40%;
  min-width: 120px;
  height: 240px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 0 0 25px 0;

 }

.wrap {
display: inherit !important;
}
 .offer > p { 
  color: black;
  font-size: .8em;
 }

 .your-yard-left {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
  border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px;
  width: 70%;
 }
 .your-yard-right {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -50px; 
  height: 260px;
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
 .offer {
  width: 30%;
 }
 .quote {
  width: 70%;
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
 .offer {
  display: none;
 }
 .quote {
  width: 100%;
 }
 .your-yard-left {
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
  top: 260px;
  overflow: none;
  width: 100%;
 }
 .your-yard-right {
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 260px;
  display: none;
 }
}

.your-yard-left {
 background-color: #A8CD1B;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 10px; 
 padding-right: 2%;
}
.your-yard-left > h2, .your-yard-left > p  {
 margin-left: 10px;
}
.your-yard-right {
 background-color: green;
 border-radius: 0 25px 25px 0;
 margin-top: 10px;
 width: 30%;
 float: right;
 z-index: 1;
 overflow: hidden;

}
.your-yard-right img {
 max-height: 150px;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 10px auto;

}
.center {
 clear: both;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1010px) {
 .your-yard {
  max-width: 1000px;
 }
 .wrap {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
 }
}

.wrap {
 display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Helping Hand Lawn Care</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">

</head>
<body>
  <!--#include virtual="includes/nav.inc"-->
  <div class="landscape">
    <div class="quote">
      <h2>Request A Quote!</h2>
      <form>
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name"><br/>
        <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email"><br/>
        <input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="Phone"><br/>
        <input type="text" id="address" placeholder="Address"><br/>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="offer">
      <h2>We'll Be In Touch</h2>
      <p>Drop us a message and we'll have one of our certified landscape technicians come by, inspect your property and give you a quote. Our prices are always fair and our service always top notch. See what </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="your-yard-left">
       <h2 class="center ">Your Yard, Your Pride, Your Way</h2>
       <p>Since 2003, Helping Hand Lawn Care has serviced homes, businesses and governmental facilities throughout the Central Florida area in full-service landscape maintenance, installation, irrigation and pest control company. Our team has the experience, knowledge and dedication it takes to invision and execute the projects it takes to get your lawn looking great.<p>
      <p>Contact us today to have a landscape professional offer a quote! We offer seasonal and annual packages for all size properties.
    </div>
    <div class="your-yard-right">
      <img src="img/landscape2.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>

    <!--
    <div class="center">
      <h2>Why Helping Hand?</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Quality work</li>
        <li>Consistent arrivals</li>
        <li>Outstanding customer service</li>
        <li>Over 15+ years industry experience</li>
    </div>
    -->



  <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/menu.js"></script>
  <!-- Other JS plugins can be included here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow! What a lovely, eloquent fix. How did you know to include that? Thanks so much!

Comment: Ohp! It didn't seem to fix the issue in Safari, which seems to be that the left and right portions of the second section are rendering too large for the wrapper? The right side is appearing beneath the left.

Answer (score 0):

So, the addition of

.wrap {
display: inherit !important
}

resolved the issue of differences in Safari and Firefox compared to Chrome. For the problem with the second section rendering vertically I noticed I had included padding-right of 2% to one of the divs without accounting for this in the divs width. Thanks for the help!